# Must I call -reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation: inside an -beginUptades -endUpdates block?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Must I call -reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation: inside an -beginUptades -endUpdates block?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends what you are trying to do.

You should use beginUpdates/endUpdates for "subsequent insertions, deletion, and selection operations (for example, cellForRowAtIndexPath: and indexPathsForVisibleRows) to be animated simultaneously" (from [UITableView beginUpdates](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW15))

However, if all you need to do is update the value of something in a cell you don't need the -reloadRowsAtIndexPaths call to be inside a beginUpdates/endUpdates.
You can actually just grab the cell directly and update the value in a lot of cases.

See [UITableView -reloadRowsAtIndexPaths](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW40) for more specifics